# I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, sse, avx

I have installed tensorflow in my CPU based system using command:

```
pip install tensorflow ==<version>
```

Installation completed without any error and as part of some initial verification I am able to see the tensorflow version installed:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'1.5.0'
```

Operating system used : Ubuntu 16.04

Now, when I tried running a python file having code to deal with a tensorflow model, I am getting the following error and the file did not execute:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2
```

I checked online for solution and could see the discussions mostly around: TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: 'AVX AVX2'(where in my case it is: 'SSE4.1 SSE4.2')

I am new to tensorflow and finding the solutions bit overwhelming.

Could you please help me to resolve this specific issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it is likely that you are missing the dependencies. Refer the below link and check if you have followed all the step by step instruction.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

It is a good practice to use package managers like Anaconda which takes care of these type of problems automatically. Following is the link:

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/